# JIRA Field Configurations and Screens

Tags: jira

I'm configuring our JIRA in that I want to make a new field configuration to configure a new project.
I'm currently going through a lot of fields, and would like to know the following:

If I remove a field from a screen in the FieldConfiguration, does that affect only my field configuration, or everyone in JIRA using that screen?

I'm sorry if I cannot describe it clearer, but basically I want to know if I break anything by removing the screen links in my Field Configuration.
Reason: I have fields assigned to 20 screens and dont want to keep scrolling through this the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean hiding a field from FieldConfiguration. Since removing fields is done in the Custom Fields section.

When you hide a field it affects only your specific Field Configuration (note than more than one Issue Type from multiple projects can associate with a Field Configuration, this is probably not your case, since your are testing a new Field Configuration. But just keep that in mind).

The action that "Hide" is doing is like "forcefully" removing that field from all screens associated with tickets which use that Field Configuration.

More data: [JIRA Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Specifying+Field+Behavior#SpecifyingFieldBehavior-hidefield)

Comment: that I know. I want to know if I click on the "Screens" link and unlink any screen in there. Does this affect only my configuration, or does this affect all those screens in JIRA regardless of the field configuration?

Comment: It will change on all screens, regardless of the field configuration. I would recommend using Hide. This is a better way to go that will make the rows "small" (one line) so you won't need to scroll a lot and won't spend a lot of time doing so.

Comment: using hide atm, but still it's a lot to scroll through.....
Don't really get the point of screen linking in Field Configurations if it doesn't store it per configuration...

Comment: I recommend you play with this in a local instance of JIRA on your laptop until it is clearer. Changing a screen that is used by multiple projects will affect all those projects